# .NET Core Distributed Redis Cache with Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, caching, redis, .net-core

I’m using the distributed Redis Cache to cache temporally some User-Data. Currently I’m testing the Application locally in my Development Environment. The Redis-Server on my local Machine has no Password but in Production I’m using a random generated Password.

How can I connect to the Redis-Server with a Password?

My Startup.cs:

```
   //Add Redis
    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
    {
        options.Configuration = "127.0.0.1:6379";
        options.InstanceName = "Portal";
    });
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` client is built on top of `StackExchange.Redis`. It means the [StackExchange Redis Connection String](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration) is used to specify a password and any other options, for example:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "localhost:6380,password=...";
    options.InstanceName = "SampleInstance";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Now I get this Error: OnActionExecuting_async:StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING

Comment: @Yannikhere, which server you try to hit? Localhost or remove? There are a lot of possible reasons: wrong connection string, network restrictions etc. Is it possible to access the server with another tool? For example, could you hit it with `redis-cli`?

Comment: My ConnectionString looks like this: 10.98.250.164:39184,ssl=true,password=PW

Comment: @Yannikhere, did you connect to this server before?

Comment: Now I set up a Redis-Server with Password locally and it's also not working

Comment: @Yannikhere, are you sure `ssl=true` is needed?